# Issue reading certificate from file in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, shell, certificate

I need to pass the certificate as a parameter in a request.
I have exported the certificate through Chrome.

Now I am trying to read it.
I tried the following after looking through a few blogs:

```
CERTIFICATE=`cat WKGLOBAL-Secure-CertificateAuthority.crt`
```

But when I check the value read into the variable, I see the below response:

```
-----BEGIN: command not found
```

Please guide me as to what I am missing.

Edit 1:
[Console snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjow2.png)

Comment: It sounds like the issue is with the way you're checking the value, not with the value itself. Can you demonstrate in full what you're doing?

Comment: @u1686_grawity: I have added link to the snapshot of the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$variable` alone is not the right way to inspect a variable's contents in Bash or similar shells.

Unlike in PowerShell, the final result after all expansions is *always* treated as a command to run, not as a value to be printed – so the first word of the expanded value becomes the command.

Use either `echo` to show the expanded value or `declare` to inspect a variable directly:

- ```
  echo "$CERTIFICATE"
  ```

  (In most cases you should have double-quotes around any shell expansion, whether it is a `$variable` or a `` `command` `` substitution. Assignments like `var=...` in your post are one of the very few exceptions where quoting can be left out without any negative effects.)
- ```
  declare -p CERTIFICATE
  ```